# Division of two values that are represented as MEAN+/-STDEV

Tags: mean, standard-deviation

Look at the article here (https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1618464/) (I am not sure if you have access to the full article, if not, let me know so that I can find a way to share it).

Basically, they measured the blood flow through liver (liter/min) as well as total cardiac output (liter/min) for a population of 178 subjects. So, the mean+/-SD for the liver blood flow for the entire population is reported to be 1.65+/-0.069 liter/min. For the cardiac output, the mean+/-SD for the same population is 8.5+/-0.2 liter/min.

Now I need to know the liver comprises what percent of the cardiac output in this population. I need this result to be presented in the form of mean+/-SD.

Thanks

Full Citation:

Paulsen, A. William, and Goran BG Klintmalm. "Direct measurement of hepatic blood flow in native and transplanted organs, with accompanying systemic hemodynamics." Hepatology 16.1 (1992): 100-111.

Comment: Percent of what?

Comment: It will depend on the shape of the distributions and their dependence.  For two independent normally distributed random variables, the expectation of the ratio is undefined

Comment: @Dave One of the measurement is a subset of another. So, the division gives you the percent contribution.

Comment: @Henry Thanks, the two measurements are independent, but I don't know about the normality of their distribution.

Comment: Please elaborate a lot more on what's going on.

Comment: @Dave Ok, will do in a minute